# Yarn Install failing on PROD build. Error - "chalk@4.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm deploying ReactJS Project on PROD environment.
Earlier it was working working but now command "Yarn install" failing.

Getting error

```
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error chalk@4.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10".
error Found incompatible module
```

No any code changes in pacakage.json

Comment: error is self-explanatory?

Comment: @xMayank but it is working in my local. not on prod. and have same nodejs version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason might be the breaking change in version 4 of Chalk[[1]](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v4.0.0). Make sure again if you really use node version 10.x in the productive environment. It is easiest to print out the version (node -v) directly in the deployment pipeline.